# Get list of keys where column equals some value?

Tags: cassandra, cql

If I have secondary index on column STATUS I would like to get all keys (within some range) that have STATUS='processed'. How can I do that without reading any columns? I just need the list of keys so only index should be accessed (one disk seek per node instead of 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secondary indexes are not directly accessible to the user, so you'd need to run an index query against the CF you've indexed and get the keys.  If you want to be guaranteed only one disk seek, you'll need to create your own index (i.e. a CF containing all "processed" keys) so you can query it directly.

Comment: That is a bummer. Creating my own index is not the same because it is not distributed and it creates hot spots.
Do you know if there is a jira issue for cassandra regarding this? It could speed up thing a lot (it is not only one additional disk seek, there can be many more disk seeks because the keys are all over the place and there are many different statuses).

Comment: Your own index would be distributed and there's no reason it would create hot spots.  I presume you're using RandomPartitioner (if not you should be), in which case any CF you create will be evenly distributed.

Comment: And I'm not aware of a JIRA, as I think this is by design.